# arrayOutOfBounds exception java on my Java project

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't seem to find the problem on the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 31

This error is received in this part of the code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < templateKeuze.length(); i++) {
  if(woord[i].startsWith("?")){
    System.out.println("\nGeef je input voor de parameter "+woord[i]);
    vervang = Input.readLine();
    templateKeuze.replace(woord[i],vervang);
  } else{
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the length of `woord` ? Note that if `templateKeuze` is a `String`, Strings are immutable so you should do `templateKeuze = templateKeuze.replace(woord[i],vervang);`.

Comment: God I'm just being retarded, been searching for an hour on this one, guess it's because I'm tired. it needed to be "woord.length()" My bad. I'm sorry. Thanks for the answer, feel free the post it as an answer

Comment: change `templateKeuze.length()` to `woord.length()`

Comment: Well you can delete this question. That won't add more value to this site.

Comment: @ZouZou i think he can cause it's an answer

Comment: Well, the error is gone, but it didn't replace the words for some reason

Comment: @Nigel As i said Strings are immutable. So it should be `templateKeuze = templateKeuze.replace(woord[i],vervang);`

Comment: Okay, I didn't read your first comment properly, I really need some sleep, thanks for the help ! I appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping up to the length of `templateKeuze`, but using that index on `woord`. Are they the same length?

Comment: Nope they weren't the same length, I was overlooking that over and over again, my bad, thanks for the help tho!